# Ansible - How to match against hosts with certain bool variable?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

Small context:

Certain hosts in my inventory need nginx access restriction. To achieve that I've implemented a bool `restrict_access: yes` and now I need to re-run my nginx setup role.

Is there a way to match *only* the hosts which have this flag set to true? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can implement that on the task level

for example:

```
# roles/webserver/tasks/main.yml  
- import_tasks: configure-nginx.yml
  when: restrict_access

- import_tasks: do-not-configure-nginx.yml
  when: not restrict_access
```